# How can I scatter each letter to a random position inside a container using CSS and javaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have few letters which I want to scatter inside a container randomly, but I'm unable to find how I can get hold of each letter and change its CSS to fix random position inside the container.
My code is as below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";


// Splitting Texts
const SplitText = React.memo(({ str }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {str.split("").map((item, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>{item}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
});

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (_) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout((_) => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }, ms);
  };
}

// Main App
export default function App() {
  //Getting the window width and height using useEffect
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
    height: window.innerHeight,
    width: window.innerWidth
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
      setDimensions({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth
      });
    }, 1000);

    window.addEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);

    return (_) => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
    };
  }); //useEffect End

  //define random position on screen
  var randLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * dimensions.width);
  var randTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * dimensions.height);
  console.log(randLeft);
  console.log(randTop);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        <SplitText str={"Lucie Bachman"} />
      </h1>
      <h2>
        <SplitText str={"Hey, this is my first post on StackOverflow!"} />
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The desired output should be like in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JustusFT/pen/ENLZGJ)

Link to my working Sandbox: [Click](https://codesandbox.io/s/scatterletters-bg0z4?file=/src/Split.js)

Any suggestion on how I can get hold of each letter would be of great help.

Comment: So what is the problem with the overlap? Is it that the letters are outside the container or is it that letters overlap with each-other? Or both?

Comment: I have added the desired output link of the CodePen. Please have a look. I want to scatter the letters as in the background.

Comment: You can create `LetterWithRandomPosition` component and memoize the `style` inside it and change the `style` when changing the props `height` or `width`